# Unable to creat an sub item on my dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to build a drop down with sub items and sub sub items;

The Sub items do work on :hover but i cant make the sub sub items do, can someone help me out?

A fiddle would be very aprettiated!

My html:

```
    <div id="menu">    
    <ul>
        <li>Mar
            <ul>
            <li><a href="">Blackbanded</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Shadow bass</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Ozark bass</a></li>
            <li><a href="">White crappie</a></li>
          </ul>
         </li>

         <li>Rio
            <ul>
            <li><a href="">Smallmouth grunt</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Burrito</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Pigfish</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li>Nascente
            <ul>
            <li><a href="">Whalesucker</a></li>

                <ul>
                <li><a href="">Welele</a></li>
                </ul>

            <li><a href="">Marlinsucker</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Ceylonese remora</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Spearfish remora</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Slender suckerfish</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

And the Css:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}

body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
}

#Content {
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
width: 750px;
height: 95%;
background: #CCC;
}







/*nav bar */ 

ul {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
}

li {
float: left;
position: relative;
width: 100px;
}

li ul {
display: none;
position: absolute; 
top: 0px;
left: 0;
}

li > ul {
top: auto;
left: auto;
}

li:hover ul { 
display: block; }


ul li ul ul li{
display: none;
position: absolute; 
top: 0px;
left: 0;
}

ul li ul li:hover ul{
display: block;
}





#menu{
width: 300px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}



/* end of nav*/
```

The [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/angus/3KecH/)

Answer (score 1):

There was an error in the html, the sub sub `ul` was outside his parent `li`.

I changed the selector `li:hover ul` for `li:hover > ul` to trigger only his direct children, so the sub sub menu stays hidden.

I also changed the selector `ul li ul ul li` for `ul li ul li ul`.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3KecH/1/